# How can I get $.getScript to work correctly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, getscript

I can see that the $.getScript bit of jquery would be handy once it's working, but it's the last little bit I'm having problems with.  I'm suspecting the problem is caused by the way I'm loading JS files.  How do I get this to work?  My index.html is actually index.php and has very little between the body tags.  I'm using jquery 1.7.1

```
<body id="btLive">
     <script>
          buildInterfaces();
     </script>
</body>
```

buildInterfaces() resides inside a document named layoutLoader.js.  In that file, I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#hToggle').click(function() {
          aaa = "Not working.";
          $.getScript('test.js', function() {
               alert(aaa);
          });
          toggleHoverPanel();
     });
});
```

As my test, test.js is in the same folder as layoutLoader.js and contains only the following:

```
aaa = "Successful Load."
```

When I click on the button hToggle, toggleHoverPanel takes place and I get no alert.  If I place an alert after aaa="Not working."; I get the alert I expect, telling me it's not working.  I have a number of items that I need to use this for, but for the life of me, I cannot get it to work.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With high probability test.js file could not by found.
Add this piece to your code and try again:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
  alert('error loading: ' + request.status);
});
```

Comment: Ah ha.  That did it.  Looks like when loading additional scripts like that, I need to make sure to specify the path relative to my index.php file and not assume that the file is in the same folder as my other scripts.

Comment: @Charles Shoults  Of course it is always related to the page or to the value of the BASE tag if it is set :)